# Lack of Content assist in Titanium

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, titanium, content-assist

I'm working on an Android mobile app, with the latest Titanium SDK (Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.0.201304151600). I'm using Windows 7 OS, Java 1.6 JDK.

The problem appears when I try to use Content assist (ctrl+space), which it doesn't work. It suggests me as far as "Ti" or "Titanium" but after that, I get no suggestions. E.g.: Titanium. doesn't result in anything.

Here are some of my settings:

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/32/73/2bCNWWaT/no-auto-complete.png))</sub>

Any ideas what could be wrong? Titanium is -as far as I can tell - based on eclipse. If anyone using eclipse might also suggest things I could try?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After the update of the Titanium Studio, this problem was resolved.

Comment: I have updated my studio but still `content assist` is not working